# Continuous Extension of Maps

Tags: general-topology

**Problem:** Let $f\colon \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^2$ be a bijective map. Can $f$ be extended to a continuous map from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$?

I tried this question with positive answer.

**Solution:** The spaces $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}^2$ are discrete subspaces (w.r.t. induced topology) of $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$, hence $f\colon \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^2$ must be continuous. By [Tietze's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_extension_theorem), $f$ can be extended to a continuous map from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$.

**Question:** Is this answer correct? Point out if any mistake is there. Further, if it is correct, I also welcome any different argument also.

Comment: Yes, it's correct. Although it's a bit overkill here, you can extend piecewise linear between $n$ and $n+1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's basically correct. $\mathbb{R}^2$ is an absolute extender (Tietze applies for codomain the reals, and this is a basic corollary), and $\mathbb{Z}$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$. So we see the original map as one from $\mathbb{Z}$ to the plane, also continuous.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose the map $f$ is given by
$f(i)=a_{i}$, for $i\in\mathbb{Z}$. Then define the extension $F$ as
 $$F(t)=(t-i)a_i+(1-t+i)a_{i+1}$$ for $i\leq t\leq i+1$ and $t>0$, and 
$$F(t)=(-t-i)a_i+(1+t+i)a_{i+1}$$ for $i\leq t\leq i+1$ and $t<0$.

So, basically $F$ is joining the points $a_i$ by straight line segments.